# How to delete files which have X days lifetime, not last modified. Is it even possible. Linux

Tags: linux, bash

I run some kind of server on my linux machine and I use simple bash script to delete files every 3 and some files every 7 days. I use find command for doing that.But my files are saved periodically, meaning that the last modification day is the current day. So files never get deleted. Only worked for me the first time, because it met the conditions. I can't find a way to delete those files using a creation date, not modification date.

Here's my simple script:

```
#!/bin/sh    
while true    
do    
java -server file.jar nogui    
echo ">$(tput setaf 3)STARTING REBOOT$(tput sgr0) $(tput setaf 7)(Ctrl+C To Stop!)$(tput sgr0)"    
find /folder/* -mtime +7 -exec rm -rf {} \;    
find /folder/* -mtime +3 -exec rm -rf {} \;    
find /logs/* -mtime +1 -exec rm -rf {} \;    
echo ">Rebooting in:"    
for i in 5 4 3 2 1    
do    
echo ">$i..."    
sleep 1    
done    
done
```

If someone could help me with this, I would be really thankful!

Comment: you have the `-ctime` option in `find` as well...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, `ctime` is not creation time.

Comment: Linux does not track the "creation date" of files. The `-ctime` parameter that @Jean-FrançoisFabre tracks the inode change time, which is also going to change every time you update the file.

Comment: ...so, what I'd suggest doing (what I do myself) is making sure that your update process doesn't overwrite the files unless the new contents differ from the old.

Comment: I suggest to start with an empty directory. Then save every day a list of your files with path to a file (e.g. files_2016115) and after three days remove all files listed in file_20161112.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible. Standard Linux filesystems do not track creation time at all. (`ctime`, sometimes mistaken for creation time, is *metadata* change time -- as compared to mtime, which is *data* modification time).

---

That said, there are certainly ugly hacks available. For instance, if you have the following script invoked by [`incron`](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en) (or, less efficiently, `cron`) to record file creation dates:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p .ctimes
for f in *; do
  if [[ -f $f ]] && [[ ! -e .ctimes/$f ]]; then
    touch ".ctimes/$f"
  fi
done
```

...then you can look for files in the `.ctimes` directory that are older than three days, and delete both the markers and the files they stand for:

```
#!/bin/bash
find .ctimes -mtime +3 -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  realname=${filename#.ctimes/}
  rm -f -- "$filename" "$realname"
done
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. Could you recommend another way to do it, can I install something. I know that it sounds lame. But that's how far I am into Linux.

Comment: The first place to start -- what's the code that's updating your files? If you can stop that process from happening when there aren't any genuine changes (or, if you want mtime to reflect creation time even if there *are* changes, touch the file with the date of the original pre-replacement version before renaming over it), then this issue goes away on its own. But any of that requires information not entered into evidence in this question.

Comment: Very good idea, but I can't alter the code, which does that, it's javascript. Changing something in that code would brake other things. Ok is there a way to make it delete something every X days, no matter what modification date is?

Comment: If you want to get into ugly hacks, we can do that -- the world is full of ugly hacks. But they're... well... ugly hacks.

Comment: @LaurynasSavickas, ...one such ugly hack added. By the way -- if the files are getting updated without your intent, how are you stopping them from being recreated after they've been deleted?

Comment: To be honest that is the fastest and best support I have ever gotten online. I already love this website! And I like that you keep it simple for Linux dumb guys like me. I have this OS for like a year and half or so.. I need to delete these folders every X days, that's a must for me. And this is where I ended up. Found nothing on google.

Comment: Glad to help! If you have the time and haven't done so already, btw, consider reading through the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) -- particularly [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -- to ensure a continuation of this quality of assistance. :)

Comment: My server is started by this script, the server knows when files are missing and it regenerates new files with reset values.   That;s what I need, to regenerate it

Comment: Ok, so I am limited to one start script, which is made so server restarts automatically if it crashes or is stopped. If I need to run 2 scripts with this hack thing, that would be impossible unless I can include this in run script. I am adding my full script so you can understand what I mean. My English is quite limited. Gimme a minute...

Comment: Added the code. I need files to be checked and deleted on the restart.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
mkdir -p .ctimes
for f in /path_to_folder/*; do
  if [[ -f $f ]] && [[ ! -e .ctimes/$f ]]; then
    touch ".ctimes/$f"
  fi
done     Is there supossed to be a path to folder? where I typed path_to_folder?

Comment: Oh and I'm getting Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "do")  while trying to execute the first script you wrote

Comment: I can't reproduce that syntax error. Could you please post the exact code, as adopted, in a gist or other *ad-free* pastebin? (Even if the code is a visual match, it's also conceivable that this could be an artifact of DOS newlines -- `$'do\r'`, ie. `do` with a `CR` character after it -- is not the same as `do`).

Answer (score 2):

Just an idea-don't shoot... :-)

If the files are not system files automatically generated by some process but is lets say server log files, you could possibly echo inside the file the creation date (i.e at the end or beginning) and grep that value later to decide if must be removed or kept.

Comment: Those files are not log files and cannot contain any other information and I can't make it to save that info inside

Comment: What about date at filename...? (either by source or even by rename...). Not possible either?

Comment: Nope, file name has to stay as it is. Which is really sad... I know where you are going...

Comment: What about using inotify tools? This guy emails new files within a directory... you could use similar technique to build an index including creation date. http://superuser.com/questions/956311/continuously-detect-new-files-with-inotify-tools-within-multiple-directories-r

Comment: That would be a solution probably, but to be honest is too complicated for me. I would need to put so much effort into to get it running. I am not truly sure if I can do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on ext4 Filesystem there is some hope. You can retrieve it using `stat` and `debugfs` utilities. ext4 stores creation time with inode table entry `i_crtime` which is 'File creation time, in seconds since the epoch' per docs. Reference [Link](http://moiseevigor.github.io/software/2015/01/30/get-file-creation-time-on-linux-with-ext4/).

Comment: New hope! Thank you, will check this link!

Comment: `debugfs` requires root, no? But accessibility with `stat` makes this very useful.

Comment: Yep, hope @LaurynasSavickas is the admin or could get sudo permission granted :D.

Comment: I am, I rent the machine.